# Appending scraped data in csv format in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I am trying to export review data from different pages of the website in csv format using the below code. Sometimes one review gets separated in different columns if we have "," in the review sentence. I want my complete reviews in one column. Can you please help?

For example: If one of the review is "We are experienced and effective problem solvers, so while it's possible this was a case of operator error, I submit others would have the same experience."

Output: Above one review sentence is getting separated in three different columns after using below code.

1st column : We are experienced and effective problem solvers

2nd column : so while it's possible this was a case of operator error

3rd column : I submit others would have the same experience.

```
sapply(df, write.table, file="D:/R Practice/texts/output.csv", append=TRUE, sep=",", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: use a ';' as the separator?

Comment: Thanks Heroka, but its not working.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example then? Makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I have edited my question above. Thanks

Comment: The code you provided is used to write data, how did you read the data. are the 3 statements in your example in a single row in your df variable?

Comment: I am scraping the data from a website and creating a data frame. Yes, 3 statements in my example is in a single row. But after writing the data, it gets separated in different columns according to ",".

Comment: What happend when you did `sep=";"` in the write.csv-command?

Comment: And why do you not use write.csv?  It handles string variables with commas in them (at least on my machine)

Comment: @Heroka: Yes i did used write.csv but i am not sure if we can append the data using write.csv